# Good design for arguments that relate to a single configuration

Tags: python, oop

Suppose we have a class that represents a box:

```
class Box:
    pass
```

It's constructor may take some arguments which represent an object, for example length, width and height:

```
class Box:

    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

Now I want to add a possibility to add shadow for the box, but it has to be optional, suppose shadow can be described with `shadowcolor` and `shadowstrength`. There are 3 ways how to add arguments that describe shadow to the constructor:

```
class Box:

    def __init__(self, ..., drop_shadow=False, shadowcolor=None, shadowstrength=None):
        if drop_shadow:
            pass
```

This is the most explicit way, but `drop_shadow` here is a bit redundant, because we can just check if `shadowcolor` and `shadowstrength` are not `None` and set shadow to box:

```
class Box:

    def __init__(self, ..., shadowcolor=None, shadowstrength=None):
        if shadowcolor and shadowstrength:
            pass
```

We dropped a redundant argument but now possibility of adding a shadow is more implicit.

Another approach would be to have a single argument - `shadow` that is a tuple of 2 arguments, where first one is `shadowcolor` and the other is `shadowstrength`:

```
class Box:

    def __init__(self, ..., shadow=None):
        self.shadowcolor = shadow[0]
        self.shadowstrength = shadow[1]
```

Now we have a single argument, but the level of implicitly is even higher.

I care about this so much because this will be used in opensource package and I want to make to make usage of a class as easy as possible.

How would you recommend to deal with this sort of 'in-constructor' configuration of another object?

Comment: This might be a better question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you have python3?

Comment: @shockawave123 yes

Comment: the shadow should be a object by itself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have your function accept a dictionary for all of the params. For example

Create:

```
parameters =  {"dropShadow": true, "shadowColor": "#019201"}
```

Pass that through

```
def __init__(self, length, width, height, params):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        for key, value in params.items():
          if key == "dropShadow":
            self.dropShadow = value
          elif key == "shadowColor"
            self.shadowColor = value
```

If you don't want to use hardcoded string (which i wouldn't suggest) then create a shape model class that defines all of the properties as static variables. for example

```
class ShapeModel:
  DROP_SHADOW = "dropShadow"
  SHADOW_COLOR = "shadowColor"
```

Then replace the above code with

```
      def __init__(self, length, width, height, params):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        for key, value in params.items():
          if key == ShapeModel.DROP_SHADOW:
            self.dropShadow = value
          elif key == ShapeModel.SHADOW_COLOR:
            self.shadowColor = value
```

Comment: Good idea, will think about if.

Want to mention that there is no need to loop over the dictionary, you can just access elements with `getattr(params, 'key', None)`

Comment: unfortunately i'm unable to update answer but i'll be able to do it by tomorrow. my apologies. feel free to edit it if you want. @pythad